# What does the reaction of chromium with ozone form?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, transition-metals

I know almost nothing beyond 10th grade chemistry. I'm trying to name a web application, and was wondering what the products are of a reaction between the element Chromium and the gas Ozone (ozonolysis of chromium?).

Comment: Chromium Oxide, Chromia, and Chrome Green would all be options, as names for various oxides of Chromium

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ozone is a strong oxidizing agent, even stronger than molecular oxygen. But it is still a donor of oxygen atoms. Thus, depending on conditions, you'll have different chromium oxides. The most stable and common chromium oxide is chromium (III) oxide $\ce{Cr2O3}$. It has numerous nicknames. Other oxides are much harder to get.

Substances named ozonides do exist and in two different flavours.

Inorganic ozonides are salts of big, inoxidizable cations, like $\ce{Cs}$ and have formulas like $\ce{KO3}$. I'm not sure which cations have ozonides that have been already produced, but to my knowledge the only reasonably easy-to-produce ozonides are $\ce{KO3}$, $\ce{RbO3}$ and $\ce{CsO3}$ by reaction of the corresponding hydroxides with ozone.

Another type of ozonides is organic ozonides that are quite weird heterocyclic compound, which are product of reaction between alkenes and ozone.

If you need a name based on word games, you may consider that chromium is a derivative of an ancient word for 'color' and ozone, as a strong oxidizer, has bleaching and antiseptic properties.

Comment: It might well form CrO3- Chromium (VI) oxide.

Comment: It might just as well form _nothing_. I don't see why the passivation of chromium would be broken by ozone.